# Hibernate: Deleting an element in child collection results in an update

Tags: hibernate

My Collection mapping file contains the following relationship:

```
<set inverse="false" lazy="true" name="collectionMembers" sort="unsorted" cascade="save-update,delete-orphan">
        <key>
            <column name="COLLECTION_CD" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="CollectionMember" />
    </set>
```

CollectionMember mapping file then contains the following bidirectional relationship:

```
<many-to-one name="collection" class="Collection" lazy="false">
        <column name="COLLECTION_CD" length="36" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
```

So a Collection contains a collection of CollectionMembers

The problem I am encountering is that when I attempt to delete a CollectionMember by removing it from the set, I get the following error message:

```
cannot update ("COLLECTION_MEMBER"."COLLECTION_CD") to NULL
```

Why is it attempting to perform an update here instead of delete?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why is it attempting to perform an update here instead of delete?*

because `inverse="false"` told Hibernate that the collection is responsible for the association which means **removing from the collection** -> **remove the association between the rows** -> **set foreign key to null**

what you propably want is `inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan"`

Comment: Yes, and there is also the needs to set update="false" as otherwise it will perform an update first.

Comment: This works and save me from an horrible workaround! Just a detail, I used: inverse="true" cascade="all-delete-orphan", without the semicolon, i add an error cascade-type "all;delete-orphan" doesn't exists